# MYSQL. Как сделать выборку по нескольким столбцам в смежной таблице

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня имеется база следующая структура базы.

```sql
create table objects
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
);

create table object_attribute_values
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    object_id int not null,
    attribute_id int not null,
    value varchar(255) null
);

create table attributes
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    attribute varchar(20) null,
);
```

И так допустим таблица attribute имеет 3 строчки:

| id | attribute |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | color |
| 2 | rating |
| 3 | size |

Необходимо сделать запрос, чтобы получить все объекты, у которых color='black', rating IN (5, 10), size=10.

Я понимаю как получить например все объекты имеющий черный цвет

```sql
SELECT o.id
FROM objects o
INNER JOIN object_attribute_values oav ON oav.object_id = o.id
INNER JOIN join attributes a ON a.id = oav.attribute_id
WHERE a.attribute = 'color' AND oav.value = 'black'
```

Но дальше не особо понимаю.

Должно получится что-то типа этого:

| object_id | attributes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | color:black,rating:6,size:10 |
| 7 | color:black,rating:6,size:10 |
| 12 | color:black,rating:9,size:10 |

Comment: Выложите пример данных в формате INSERT INTO, а не таблицей (впрочем. её можно оставить). Покажите требуемый ответ строго для предоставленных исходных данных и озвученного набора критериев.

Comment: *дальше не особо понимаю.* дальше группировка по объекту и отбор по условным агрегатам.

Comment: PS. А за каким в таблице связности синтетический ключ? Естественный по трём полям как бы напрашивается... и в таблице атрибутов отсутствие ограничения уникальности на атрибут - тоже нехорошо.